# How can I fix samba mounting after upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, mount, samba

I upgraded my media server from 14.04 to 16.04 and it has completely broken samba mounting. I had an auto-mount set up in `/etc/fstab` that IIRC looked like this (I've been messing around with it for the better part of two days it's hard to remember exactly what has been added/removed):

```
//eir.local/media /media/nas-media cifs username=Loki,password=*****,iocharset=utf8
```

I've tried various iterations of fixing this including sec=ntlm 0 0, sec=ntlmv2 and so on, but ultimately the problem seems deeper than this. Any attempt at mounting seems to end up with the same "Unable to find suitable address" error:

```
thor@loki:~$ sudo mount -t cifs -o username=Loki //eir.local/Media /media/nas-media/
Password for Loki@//eir.local/Media:  ********************
Unable to find suitable address.
```

And in the log `/var/log/kern.log` the following two lines (only) appear:

```
Nov 13 11:55:32 loki kernel: [263331.971834] CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation.
Nov 13 11:55:32 loki kernel: [263331.972092] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -111
```

I've been browsing through so many questions and answers on here I couldn't really give a concise run-down of what I've tried to debug this (should have kept a record I suppose), but some highlights include reinstalling `cifs-utils`, `samba-common` (including overwriting my config), trying different samba shares, using `smbclient` to list shares, running `dpkg-reconfigure samba-common`, and of course rebooting and updating all packages. I'm really running out of ideas at this point so I'm hoping there's something obvious I've missed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully someone could come up with a better solution, but in the end I had to just go with reinstalling the OS. I ended up going with Mint instead though, which for some reason handled my Mac Mini's graphics card better too. I'll leave this question here in case someone comes up with some alternative answers for others in a similar boat in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm,

Although i am at 18.04 ubuntu server and 2 years further down the road i have exactly the same problem as to be found here:

[After 18.04.01 LTS server update samba returns unable to find suitable address message](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1084040/after-18-04-01-lts-server-update-samba-returns-unable-to-find-suitable-address-m)

Cannot image i am the only one with the messed up Samba server after the update.

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

ADDED LATER:

The probable solution can be found on the link provided. Package libtevent0 probably caused your problems.