# CIFS auto mounting fails after upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: networking, mount, samba, fstab

Similar to [How can I fix samba mounting after upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/848896/how-can-i-fix-samba-mounting-after-upgrading-from-14-04-to-16-04)

I have credential files set up in my root directory and an auto mount for several network drives (QNAP and DLNK) that has been working since 12.04. Sample `/etc/fstab` entry:

`//192.168.1.99/Multimedia /media/Multimedia cifs credentials=/root/.my_credentials,iocharset=utf8,noperm,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0`

Yet, even though they are permanently mounted in my `/etc/fstab` - Nautilus will respond with a `Only Root can mount`.

Dropping to a terminal and executing `sudo mount -a` results in `Unable to find suitable address.`

However, I can connect using `Connect to server` from Nautilus and I don't have to sign in, it logs me in, and then all of my mapped drives for that device are visible.

`Looking at dmesg shows the following:
[    6.310007] EXT4-fs (sda5): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: discard,commit=600,errors=remount-ro
[    6.336488] FS-Cache: Loaded
[    6.367401] FS-Cache: Netfs 'cifs' registered for caching
[    6.368495] Key type cifs.spnego registered
[    6.368499] Key type cifs.idmap registered
[    6.377488] CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation.
[    6.378212] CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation.
[    6.378213] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -101
[    6.379287] CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation.
[    6.379618] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -101
[    6.380107] CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation.
[    6.380366] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -101
[    6.381863] CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation.
[    6.382462] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -101
[    6.384128] CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation.`

It looks like a CIFS fault.