# After 18.04.01 LTS server update samba returns unable to find suitable address message

Tags: server, mount, samba, fstab, bugzilla

So, at first Samba worked even after the update, Due to lack of GB on server side hard drive i changed the label of a drive. altered all i needed to relevant places and files. All worked, could acces from windows laptop and linux laptop.

After a couple of days i noticed drives were not mounted on my linux laptop. thinked not to much of it yet. My wife complaints that the server is unreachable and now after investigating i ran out of options :

```
tail -f /var/log/kernel.log
```

gave the following in the beginning :

```
Oct 15 21:43:07 Laptop kernel: [ 3910.412985] No dialect specified on mount. Default has changed to a more secure dialect, SMB2.1 or later (e.g. SMB3), from CIFS (SMB1). To use the less secure SMB1 dialect to access old servers which do not support SMB3 (or SMB2.1) specify vers=1.0 on mount.
Oct 15 21:43:07 Laptop kernel: [ 3910.418005] CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation.
Oct 15 21:43:07 Laptop kernel: [ 3910.418016] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -111
```

so i changed /etc/fstab entry and added :

```
/media/movies cifs auto,*`vers=1.0`*,credentials=/etc/samba/user,noexec 0 0
```

which only left me with :

```
Oct 15 21:49:06 Laptop kernel: [ 4269.887208] CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation.
Oct 15 21:49:06 Laptop kernel: [ 4269.887218] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -111
```

So i got the version right, but now it leaves me with return code -111 which google says basicly anything can be wrong.

On the server side :
service smb status gives

```
>● smb.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)

service smbd status
>● smbd.service - LSB: start Samba SMB/CIFS daemon (smbd)
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/smbd; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Mon 2018-10-15 21:11:36 CEST; 43min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 1136 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/smbd start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Oct 15 21:11:38 rabbithole smbd[1159]:    #10 /usr/sbin/smbd(main+0x1899) [0x55c64af04099]
Oct 15 21:11:38 rabbithole smbd[1159]:    #11 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe7) [0x7f410b059b97]
Oct 15 21:11:38 rabbithole smbd[1159]:    #12 /usr/sbin/smbd(_start+0x29) [0x55c64af04199]
Oct 15 21:11:38 rabbithole smbd[1159]: [2018/10/15 21:11:38.090690,  0] ../source3/lib/util.c:801(smb_panic_s3)
Oct 15 21:11:38 rabbithole smbd[1159]:   smb_panic(): calling panic action [/usr/share/samba/panic-action 1159]
Oct 15 21:11:38 rabbithole smbd[1159]: [2018/10/15 21:11:38.098636,  0] ../source3/lib/util.c:809(smb_panic_s3)
Oct 15 21:11:38 rabbithole smbd[1159]:   smb_panic(): action returned status 0
Oct 15 21:11:38 rabbithole smbd[1159]: [2018/10/15 21:11:38.098738,  0] ../source3/lib/dumpcore.c:303(dump_core)
Oct 15 21:11:38 rabbithole smbd[1159]:   dumping core in /var/log/samba/cores/smbd
Oct 15 21:11:38 rabbithole smbd[1159]:
```

probably everybody notices the obvious, but my knowledge is not that great, so i hope people here know some other solutions or maybe give me pointers as i think this goes beyond novice level :)

Maybe the best advise is to copy /etc/samba/smb.conf and re install samba. or run an alternative (is there any?)

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
16-10-2018 added:

looks more and more that the server side isn't available : 
when using

```
sudo smbclient -L //server_ip -U user
```

i get prompted for user password which after i am certain i added the correct password :

```
WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
Enter diet's password: 
Connection to 192.168.178.21 failed (Error NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_REFUSED)
```

Added more :

When command nmblookup is performed on client side, the server does not show, tried various variations of the command, but the servers ip address did not show. smbtree also gives no server.

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
ADDED 18-10-2018

I have been digging deeper into the panic reaction and looked into the log files /var/log/samba/log.nmdb where i found the following

```
diet@rabbithole:~$ sudo cat /var/log/samba/log.nmbd 
[2018/10/15 21:11:36.244286,  0] ../lib/util/become_daemon.c:124(daemon_ready)
  STATUS=daemon 'nmbd' finished starting up and ready to serve connections
[2018/10/15 21:11:36.244592,  0] ../lib/util/fault.c:78(fault_report)
  ===============================================================
[2018/10/15 21:11:36.244651,  0] ../lib/util/fault.c:79(fault_report)
  INTERNAL ERROR: Signal 11 in pid 1135 (4.3.11-Ubuntu)
  Please read the Trouble-Shooting section of the Samba HOWTO
[2018/10/15 21:11:36.244708,  0] ../lib/util/fault.c:81(fault_report)
  ===============================================================
[2018/10/15 21:11:36.244750,  0] ../source3/lib/util.c:789(smb_panic_s3)
  PANIC (pid 1135): internal error
[2018/10/15 21:11:36.245703,  0] ../source3/lib/util.c:900(log_stack_trace)
  BACKTRACE: 11 stack frames:
   #0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsmbregistry.so.0(log_stack_trace+0x1a) [0x7f58521627aa]
   #1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsmbregistry.so.0(smb_panic_s3+0x20) [0x7f5852162880]
   #2 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamba-util.so.0(smb_panic+0x2f) [0x7f585445ff1f]
   #3 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamba-util.so.0(+0x1b136) [0x7f5854460136]
   #4 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x12890) [0x7f58548c4890]
   #5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtalloc.so.2(talloc_get_size+0x5) [0x7f58517005a5]
   #6 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0(event_add_to_poll_args+0x76) [0x7f5853846556]
   #7 /usr/sbin/nmbd(listen_for_packets+0xff) [0x5590a81f47af]
   #8 /usr/sbin/nmbd(main+0xcf6) [0x5590a81e3bb6]
   #9 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe7) [0x7f5850cfbb97]
   #10 /usr/sbin/nmbd(_start+0x29) [0x5590a81e3f79]
[2018/10/15 21:11:36.245966,  0] ../source3/lib/util.c:801(smb_panic_s3)
  smb_panic(): calling panic action [/usr/share/samba/panic-action 1135]
[2018/10/15 21:11:36.259765,  0] ../source3/lib/util.c:809(smb_panic_s3)
  smb_panic(): action returned status 0
[2018/10/15 21:11:36.260473,  0] ../source3/lib/dumpcore.c:303(dump_core)
  dumping core in /var/log/samba/cores/nmbd
[2018/10/16 22:25:50.464532,  0] ../lib/util/become_daemon.c:124(daemon_ready)
  STATUS=daemon 'nmbd' finished starting up and ready to serve connections
[2018/10/16 22:25:50.501751,  0] ../lib/util/fault.c:78(fault_report)
  ===============================================================
[2018/10/16 22:25:50.501817,  0] ../lib/util/fault.c:79(fault_report)
  INTERNAL ERROR: Signal 11 in pid 1069 (4.3.11-Ubuntu)
  Please read the Trouble-Shooting section of the Samba HOWTO
[2018/10/16 22:25:50.501886,  0] ../lib/util/fault.c:81(fault_report)
  ===============================================================
[2018/10/16 22:25:50.501927,  0] ../source3/lib/util.c:789(smb_panic_s3)
  PANIC (pid 1069): internal error
[2018/10/16 22:25:50.502887,  0] ../source3/lib/util.c:900(log_stack_trace)
  BACKTRACE: 11 stack frames:
   #0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsmbregistry.so.0(log_stack_trace+0x1a) [0x7f58a6df07aa]
   #1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsmbregistry.so.0(smb_panic_s3+0x20) [0x7f58a6df0880]
   #2 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamba-util.so.0(smb_panic+0x2f) [0x7f58a90edf1f]
   #3 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamba-util.so.0(+0x1b136) [0x7f58a90ee136]
   #4 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x12890) [0x7f58a9552890]
   #5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtalloc.so.2(talloc_get_size+0x5) [0x7f58a638e5a5]
   #6 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0(event_add_to_poll_args+0x76) [0x7f58a84d4556]
   #7 /usr/sbin/nmbd(listen_for_packets+0xff) [0x5626ea7dc7af]
   #8 /usr/sbin/nmbd(main+0xcf6) [0x5626ea7cbbb6]
   #9 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe7) [0x7f58a5989b97]
   #10 /usr/sbin/nmbd(_start+0x29) [0x5626ea7cbf79]
[2018/10/16 22:25:50.503153,  0] ../source3/lib/util.c:801(smb_panic_s3)
  smb_panic(): calling panic action [/usr/share/samba/panic-action 1069]
[2018/10/16 22:25:50.512666,  0] ../source3/lib/util.c:809(smb_panic_s3)
  smb_panic(): action returned status 0
[2018/10/16 22:25:50.512764,  0] ../source3/lib/dumpcore.c:303(dump_core)
  dumping core in /var/log/samba/cores/nmbd
[2018/10/18 19:44:06.860935,  0] ../lib/util/become_daemon.c:124(daemon_ready)
  STATUS=daemon 'nmbd' finished starting up and ready to serve connections
[2018/10/18 19:44:06.894869,  0] ../lib/util/fault.c:78(fault_report)
  ===============================================================
[2018/10/18 19:44:06.894939,  0] ../lib/util/fault.c:79(fault_report)
  INTERNAL ERROR: Signal 11 in pid 1046 (4.3.11-Ubuntu)
  Please read the Trouble-Shooting section of the Samba HOWTO
[2018/10/18 19:44:06.894998,  0] ../lib/util/fault.c:81(fault_report)
  ===============================================================
[2018/10/18 19:44:06.895041,  0] ../source3/lib/util.c:789(smb_panic_s3)
  PANIC (pid 1046): internal error
[2018/10/18 19:44:06.896034,  0] ../source3/lib/util.c:900(log_stack_trace)
  BACKTRACE: 11 stack frames:
   #0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsmbregistry.so.0(log_stack_trace+0x1a) [0x7f1e44bbf7aa]
   #1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsmbregistry.so.0(smb_panic_s3+0x20) [0x7f1e44bbf880]
   #2 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamba-util.so.0(smb_panic+0x2f) [0x7f1e46ebcf1f]
   #3 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamba-util.so.0(+0x1b136) [0x7f1e46ebd136]
   #4 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x12890) [0x7f1e47321890]
   #5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtalloc.so.2(talloc_get_size+0x5) [0x7f1e4415d5a5]
   #6 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0(event_add_to_poll_args+0x76) [0x7f1e462a3556]
   #7 /usr/sbin/nmbd(listen_for_packets+0xff) [0x55ff3c5c47af]
   #8 /usr/sbin/nmbd(main+0xcf6) [0x55ff3c5b3bb6]
   #9 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe7) [0x7f1e43758b97]
   #10 /usr/sbin/nmbd(_start+0x29) [0x55ff3c5b3f79]
[2018/10/18 19:44:06.896297,  0] ../source3/lib/util.c:801(smb_panic_s3)
  smb_panic(): calling panic action [/usr/share/samba/panic-action 1046]
[2018/10/18 19:44:06.906076,  0] ../source3/lib/util.c:809(smb_panic_s3)
  smb_panic(): action returned status 0
[2018/10/18 19:44:06.906178,  0] ../source3/lib/dumpcore.c:303(dump_core)
  dumping core in /var/log/samba/cores/nmbdADDED 18-10-2018
```

Google Led me to [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1375973) where i find "exactly" the same fault codes.

Now is the question, how do i get this solved? how do i downgrade to libtevent 0.9.28 to see if this gets it fixed?

i found [this page](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/libtevent-dev/download) so i know it is in older repositories, which i added but when i use

```
diet@rabbithole:~$ sudo apt-get install libtevent-dev=0.9.28-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
```

i get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libtevent-dev : Depends: libtevent0 (= 0.9.28-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) but 0.9.34-1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Although i think i am on to something, i am wondering why i am having this issue after updating to 18.04. the buzilla report dates from a while back with solutions mentioned that i cannot roll out yet because off my lack of skills to do a rollback on a package and its dependencies.

Comment: Check your `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file on the server and make sure that there is no line stating something like `min protocol=` or `server min protocol=`  and if it does exist try commenting it out and restart the Samba daemon `systemctl restart smbd.service`

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, could not find the line you mentioned so i guess this should not interfere.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got it solved by rolling back libtevent to 0.9.28

commands used :

First i added the following repository to /etc/apt.sources.list :

```
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main
```

then did

```
sudo apt-get update
```

now you can do 2 options where option 2 gives less output

option 1

```
sudo apt-cache showpkg libtevent0
```

option 2

```
sudo apt-cache policy libtevent0
```

you will see that older versions will be available

next

```
sudo apt-get install libtevent0=0.9.28-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
```

press y and enter

and the roll back is a fact.

```
sudo service smbd restart && sudo service smbd status

    ● smbd.service - LSB: start Samba SMB/CIFS daemon (smbd)
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/smbd; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2018-10-18 21:31:59 CEST; 9min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 3798 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/smbd stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 3812 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/smbd start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/smbd.service
           ├─3826 /usr/sbin/smbd -D
           ├─3827 /usr/sbin/smbd -D
           ├─3829 /usr/sbin/smbd -D
           ├─3847 /usr/sbin/smbd -D
           └─3848 /usr/sbin/smbd -D

Oct 18 21:31:58 rabbithole systemd[1]: Starting LSB: start Samba SMB/CIFS daemon (smbd)...
Oct 18 21:31:59 rabbithole smbd[3812]:  * Starting SMB/CIFS daemon smbd
Oct 18 21:31:59 rabbithole smbd[3812]:    ...done.
Oct 18 21:31:59 rabbithole systemd[1]: Started LSB: start Samba SMB/CIFS daemon (smbd).
Oct 18 21:31:59 rabbithole smbd[3826]: [2018/10/18 21:31:59.315254,  0] ../lib/util/become_daemon.c:124(daemon_ready)
Oct 18 21:31:59 rabbithole smbd[3826]:   STATUS=daemon 'smbd' finished starting up and ready to serve connections
Oct 18 21:32:26 rabbithole smbd[3847]: pam_unix(samba:session): session opened for user diet by (uid=0)
Oct 18 21:32:26 rabbithole smbd[3848]: pam_unix(samba:session): session opened for user diet by (uid=0)
```

for safety i marked the libtevent package not to be updated anymore. not sure yet what the consequences will be in the future.

```
sudo apt-mark hold libtevent0
```

Hope this will help others whom may encounter the same issue as i did.