# resolvconf-pull-resolved.path error

Tags: networking, server, resolvconf

GoodDay all,

New day, new linux adventures on my home server:

```
Can resolvconf-pull-resolved.path be blocking my servers internet connection ?
```

Background info:

I updated/upgraded my server to the latest updates recently, following the routine execution of apt update && apt upgrade and went to work.

Later I was trying to ssh to my server on the static IP address I have for it, but there was no connection. Figured I needed to reboot the server and I should be good to go again and ran off again. Sometime later I ssh again to the server, still found no connection to host. By then I got worried.

Booting the system while looking to the screen I noticed the first [FAILED] to be resolvconf-pull-resolved and a bit later unable to bring op networking (second [FAILED]).

Tried some stuff already like this page, but that did not help.

Tried journalctl -xe and got a lot of stuff in red. But I did not seem to get to the bottom of why this is happening.

So now I am wondering if there are 2 problems, or that it is 1 problem that leads to another. As I know my around Linux a bit to do basic stuff, this is way above my knowledge.

Any pointers are well appreciated and I would like to say thanks in advance for any help.

I already have a new live USB stick hanging around for reinstalling the server, but then again, what is the fun in that.

PS: Other intel information on my server can be found [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1084040/after-18-04-01-lts-server-update-samba-returns-unable-to-find-suitable-address-m).

Where I have an update hold on libtevent > hope that there is no version conflict

So again, can somebody shed light on this?

EDIT:

> systemctl status resolvconf-pull-resolved.path

`● resolvconf-pull-resolved.path
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/resolvconf-pull-resolved.path; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
Jan 22 21:46:48 rabbithole systemd1: resolvconf-pull-resolved.path: Refusing to start, unit to trigger not loaded.
Jan 22 21:46:48 rabbithole systemd1: Failed to start resolvconf-pull-resolved.path.`

> systemctl status resolvconf-pull-resolved.service

`● resolvconf-pull-resolved.service
   Loaded: error (Reason: Invalid argument)
   Active: inactive (dead)`

> systemctl status resolvconf.service

`● resolvconf.service - Nameserver information manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/resolvconf.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Tue 2019-01-22 21:46:47 CET; 4min 10s ago
     Docs: man:resolvconf(8)
  Process: 545 ExecStart=/sbin/resolvconf --enable-updates (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 538 ExecStartPre=/bin/touch /run/resolvconf/postponed-update (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 535 ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /run/resolvconf/interface (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 545 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/resolvconf.service
Jan 22 21:46:47 rabbithole systemd1: Starting Nameserver information manager...
Jan 22 21:46:47 rabbithole systemd1: Started Nameserver information manager.
Jan 22 21:46:47 rabbithole resolvconf[545]: /etc/resolvconf/update.d/libc: Warning: /etc/resolv.conf is not a symbolic link to /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`

Comment: I would really appreciate if you could cut the story out, and focused on the problem with some error logs or statistics.

Comment: Thanks for your help > if you don't mind i have Copied and pasted your amended text into my post > and added various systemctl status output which hopefully will add information.

Answer (score 0):

So, after doing more server research i also had an error with my network devices. Because the above was not so easy i thought to give the other failure a look:

> sudo systemctl status networking.service returned this :

```
 ● networking.service - Raise network interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor preset:      
   enabled)
  Drop-In: /run/systemd/generator/networking.service.d
           └─50-insserv.conf-$network.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2019-01-26 22:47:08 CET; 15min ago
     Docs: man:interfaces(5)
 Main PID: 707 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 26 22:47:07 rabbithole systemd[1]: Starting Raise network interfaces...
Jan 26 22:47:07 rabbithole sh[702]: Unknown interface eth0
Jan 26 22:47:08 rabbithole ifup[707]: Unknown interface eth0
Jan 26 22:47:08 rabbithole systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited,     
                code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 26 22:47:08 rabbithole systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
Jan 26 22:47:08 rabbithole systemd[1]: networking.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 26 22:47:08 rabbithole systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result'exit-code'.
```

and

> sudo networkctl list

Gave me

```
 IDX LINK             TYPE               OPERATIONAL SETUP     
1 lo               loopback           carrier     unmanaged 
2 eth0             ether              off         unmanaged 

2 links listed.
```

As i am not an IT guy it took me sometime to realize that my network just was not on.

> cat /etc/network/interfaces

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo eth0
    iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
    iface dhcp inet dhcp
```

By then i thought the network card was just not working

> lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 82G33/G31/P35/P31 Express DRAM Controller (rev 02)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82G33/G31/P35/P31 Express PCI Express Root Port (rev 02)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 02)
00:1a.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (rev 02)
00:1a.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6 (rev 02)
00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 02)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 02)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 5 (rev 02)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 6 (rev 02)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 02)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev 92)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801IB (ICH9) LPC Interface Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801IB (ICH9) 2 port SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 02)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.5 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) 2 port SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 02)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT215 [GeForce GT 240] (rev a2)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros Attansic L1 Gigabit Ethernet (rev b0)
03:00.0 SATA controller: JMicron Technology Corp. JMB363 SATA/IDE Controller (rev 03)
03:00.1 IDE interface: JMicron Technology Corp. JMB363 SATA/IDE Controller (rev 03)
05:03.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): VIA Technologies, Inc. VT6306/7/8 [Fire II(M)] IEEE 1394 OHCI Controller (rev c0)
```

But this showed the Network card without any issues so now i thought something else must be wrong.

So then i did (no idea where i found this)

> sudo dhclient

which gave me :

```
/etc/resolvconf/update.d/libc: Warning: /etc/resolv.conf is not a symbolic link to /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
```

So then things got complicated for me as i was not sure what it meant. for some reason, maybe because i followed instructions somewhere

> networkctl status

which then gave me :

```
● 2: eth0
   Link File: /lib/systemd/network/99-default.link
Network File: n/a
        Type: ether
       State: routable (unmanaged)
        Path: pci-0000:02:00.0
      Driver: atl1
      Vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       Model: Attansic L1 Gigabit Ethernet (P5KPL-VM Motherboard)
  HW Address: 00:1b:fc:5a:3c:7e (ASUSTek COMPUTER INC.)
     Address: 192.168.178.37
              fe80::21b:fcff:fe5a:3c7e
     Gateway: 192.168.178.1 (Cisco SPVTG)
```

where the state : routable (unmanaged) turned up green.

tried ping 8.8.8.8 which gave an instant answer. Then i thought i had fixed it, did apt-update && apt-upgrade which went well, rebooted > no internet

being the idiot as i am i did

> sudo dhclient again with the same result :

```
● 2: eth0
   Link File: /lib/systemd/network/99-default.link
Network File: n/a
        Type: ether
       State: routable (unmanaged)
        Path: pci-0000:02:00.0
      Driver: atl1
      Vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       Model: Attansic L1 Gigabit Ethernet (P5KPL-VM Motherboard)
  HW Address: 00:1b:fc:5a:3c:7e (ASUSTek COMPUTER INC.)
     Address: 192.168.178.37
              fe80::21b:fcff:fe5a:3c7e
     Gateway: 192.168.178.1 (Cisco SPVTG)
```

Internet back up again

Did

> systemctl status resolvconf.service

```
● resolvconf.service - Nameserver information manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/resolvconf.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Sat 2019-01-26 23:29:31 CET; 25min ago
         Docs: man:resolvconf(8)
  Process: 547 ExecStart=/sbin/resolvconf --enable-updates (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 542 ExecStartPre=/bin/touch /run/resolvconf/postponed-update (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 538 ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /run/resolvconf/interface (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 547 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/resolvconf.service

Jan 26 23:29:31 rabbithole systemd[1]: Starting Nameserver information manager...
Jan 26 23:29:31 rabbithole systemd[1]: Started Nameserver information manager.
Jan 26 23:29:31 rabbithole resolvconf[547]: /etc/resolvconf/update.d/libc: Warning: /etc/resolv.conf is not a symbolic link to /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
```

funny part in this story that i just now realize that the final line is the same code sudo dhclient returned.

So the resolvconf situation clearly has been caused by the eth0 not being up.

This story probably could have been a lot shorter but then some admin probably will shorten it :) Or correct my grammar.